# How do I get a Realtek 8821 wireless card working?

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I have a Transformer Book Trio, and just like [there](http://www.libre-software.net/ubuntu-linux-mint-on-asus-transformer-book-trio), Ubuntu seems not to see the wifi card. Here are the two commandlines I used :

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

$ lspci -nn | grep -i net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8821]
```

Answer (score 3):

According to http://wikidevi.com/wiki/Realtek_RTL8821AE_Combo_Module a staging driver is available in kernel 3.14 and a final is expected in kernel 3.15+.

Also, SteamOS already includes an experimental driver for the chipset:

- http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamuniverse/discussions/1/558746088887100821/

Answer (score 3):

I got this chipset working with linux kernel 3.14-rc1 staging drivers by following instructions under "Wifi Notes" at http://www.linlap.com/asus_transformer_book_trio_tx201la

Comment: So did I, although the WiFi cannot find my network...

Answer (score 2):

I exchanged email with Realtek today.   They confirmed there are no linux drivers for this device yet.

However, the good news is that this chip set is included in the Gigabyte BRIX Pro which was distributed to all attendees of the Steam DevDays conference where SteamOS (based on linux) was announced.

There are likely many capable developers with this device in their hands.  Hopefully a production driver is forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no device driver in Linux for this device. If you have or can find a Windows XP driver, you may be able to get it going with ndiswrapper. ndiswrapper requires XP and will not work with Windows Vista, 7 or 8 driver files.

I suggest you register and file a bug report asking for support: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Ok team. I am as fresh a rookie as you can possibly have in computers, and i have been having this same issue for the last 4 days since i decided to dual boot Ubuntu 15.04 to learn Linux. After countless terminal commands found on various forums and exponential frustration, i chanced upon another forum that again asked me to install the drivers for my RTL8821AE but make sure the older drivers were blacklisted. So this got me thinking and i decided to do some edits (with screenshots of course, to undo the damage I was planning!). After these changes i rebooted. And EUREKA!

And yeah  - my response might be a year or too late after its already been solved......but i just wanted to throw it out there!
Pass it on.....

***vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf***

```
# Commented out followed lines
# install rtl8192cu /bin/false
# install rtl8192c_common /bin/false
# install rtlwifi /bin/false
```

***vim /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8821ae.conf***

```
# change ips and fwlps from 0 to 1
options rtl8821ae swenc=1 ips=1 fwlps=1
# You can also try ant_sel=1/ant_sel=2 to hardcode selected antenna
```

***After doing that reboot or reload driver:***

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8821ae
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

I am hoping I am doing this right and you all can see the images. 
Disclaimer: Apart from being the rookiest rookie in computers, I am also one when it comes to posting in forum/threads.

So please pardon my ignorance. I just wanted to share this in the hopes that someone else gets lucky like i did.

Thank You to the countless forums and threads out there about this issue, without which I would never have had the idea to try these changes.
And to a special mentor i met today at Fry's. Damn smart guy.

Hope to be around more and learn from experts like everyone else here!
Cheers!

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought i added screenshots when i was posting. I will go home in the evening and try to add them again.